# Communicate between iOS App and Raspberry Pi BLE

Tags: swift, python-3.x, bluetooth

I am working on an BLE App to communicate with the Raspberry Pi 3. With the iOS app I want to send a Signal and the raspberry has to receive it. The Python code is waiting for a notification.

I got several articles for each side the iOS app and the Raspberry Pi but none of them work together.

iOS code:

```
@IBAction func ButtonSet1 (_ sender: Any) {         // Button defenition SET

        let string = "1"

        let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let characteristic = servoCharacteristic
        //get right on out of _characteristics! array
        _peripheral?.writeValue((data)!, for: characteristic!, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)


        print(data!)
    }
```

Python 3 code:

```py
from bluepy import btle

class MyDelegate(btle.DefaultDelegate):
    def __init__(self):
        btle.DefaultDelegate.__init__(self)

    def handleNotification(self, cHandle, data):
        print("A notification was received: %s" %data)

p = btle.Peripheral("44:00:10:28:63:ac")
p.setDelegate( MyDelegate() )

# Setup to turn notifications on, e.g.
svc = p.getServiceByUUID("d0611e78-bbb4-4591-a5f8-487910ae4366")
ch = svc.getCharacteristics()[0]
print('ch.valHandle')


while True:

    p.waitForNotifications(1)
        # handleNotification() was called

    if p==1:
        print('1')

    else:
        print('0')

    pass

p.disconnect()
```

on Both sides I don't get any errors but they don't communicate with each other.

Comment: Does this code help initiate the pairing, or is the pairing done, and you are just sending data? If you are sending from iOS to the RP, then I wonder if one or more of the methods on the iOS side will return results to you that you can interrogate for success/fail data. I assume it would be the `writeValue` function? What is `_peripheral`, is that an instance variable of a BLE class or similar?

Comment: I don't know any of these technologies, but I wonder if there is enough information here for a reader to be able to replicate what you have done. Does it need any more code to get the waiting-state you have?

Comment: the pairing is done before and I am just sending the data. A main topic is also that the pairing could be done from both sides. I am able to connect from the iOS side and the based on the code the raspbeery connects also to the phone. the '''_peripheral''' is defined by '''var _peripheral: CBPeripheral?''' Hope it helps

Comment: @halfer sorry haven't marked you see answer above

Comment: OK, if you have an answer, would expand on that, and add a full answer below? We welcome self-answers here.